# Failing to Drop Database in Hive

Tags: hive, amazon-emr

I'm trying to initialize database in hive before each run.

The code is:

```
command="hive -e \"drop database if exists some_db cascade; create database some_db\"";
eval $command;
```

execution fails with error:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Unable to clean up java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hive.COMPLETED_COMPACTIONS' doesn't exist

it passes on rerun,

```
eval $command;
```

I can't explain also the fact that when calling the command for multiple times, it keep failing alternately.

Appreciate for advice to what happens in Hive and how to make it work on the first attempt, thanks.

---

Details:
Hive 2.1 running on AWS EMR 5.7, didn't see such behavior on HIVE 1.0

Full Error Stack

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Unable to clean up java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hive.COMPLETED_COMPACTIONS' doesn't exist
>           at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:125)
>           at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.throwException(ExceptionMapper.java:69)
>           at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeQueryEpilog(MariaDbStatement.java:259)
>           at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.execute(MariaDbStatement.java:287)
>           at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeUpdate(MariaDbStatement.java:470)
>           at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeUpdate(MariaDbStatement.java:486)
>           at com.jolbox.bonecp.StatementHandle.executeUpdate(StatementHandle.java:497)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.txn.TxnHandler.cleanupRecords(TxnHandler.java:1721)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.AcidEventListener.onDropDatabase(AcidEventListener.java:51)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.drop_database_core(HiveMetaStore.java:1098)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.drop_database(HiveMetaStore.java:1130)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:140)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:99)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.drop_database(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$drop_database.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:10518)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$drop_database.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:10502)
>           at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor$1.run(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:110)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor$1.run(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:106)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor.process(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:118)
>           at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Table 'hive.COMPLETED_COMPACTIONS' doesn't exist
>           at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:479)
>           at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.result(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:400)
>           at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:381)
>           at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:337)
>           at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.execute(MariaDbStatement.java:277)
>           ... 27 more
>   Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Hive metastore schema needs to be upgraded. You can check the schema version with the [schematool](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool) command.

Example output:

Metastore connection URL:        jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
Metastore Connection Driver :    org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
Metastore connection User:       hive
Hive distribution version:       2.1.0
Metastore schema version:        2.1.0

If your metastore schema and Hive distribution versions are not the same, upgrade the schema.

Make sure you have a backup first, just in case. Also remember that there could be changes to the schema that breaks functionality with older Hive distributions so you may not be able to share a matastore between Hive distribution versions.

Comment: it makes sense, thanks, we'll test it and I'll update